# How to express idempotent (self flatten) types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There are types with self flattening nature that is called Idempotence:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

> Idempotence  is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science whereby they can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application.

In JavaScript/TypeScript, we have **Object/Number object** for instance of idempotence.

A real world use-case is to write your own Promises with proper type in TypeScript. You can never have `Promise<Promise<T>>` only ever `Promise<T>` since promises auto-flatten. The same can happen with monads, for example.

```js
console.log(
 Number(5) === Number(Number(5))
); // true
```

In a concise way, it's often expressed like

**TTX = TX**

Edit:
in fact, this can be somewhat confusing concept; because Idempotent never has structure more than T, in JS array form `[foo]`.
On the other hand monads operation (bind in Haskel word) is TTX = TX, but it does have structure like `[[foo]]`.

`Array.map` composition is `[[foo]] => [[[foo]]]`

`Array.flatMap` composition map+flat(TTX=TX) is `[[foo]] => [[foo]]`

this is monad, but not Idempotent, I think. Confusing, yes.

I somehow managed to write in function

```
const toObject = <A, X>(x: A): A extends T<X> ? A : //...
        ((X:object)=> {/* ... */})(Object(x)) ;
```

`A extends T<X> ? A : //...` works in the context of inside of some functions, but I don't know how to write the type itself alone, and even with function structure, it's very complicated, and I feel something is very wrong.

What I want to know and write is a definition of the idempotent type in TypeScript

```
type T<X> = ???
//where
T<T<X>> === T<X>
```

Comment: Can you give a real-world example where being able to type things this way would be useful? Because `Number` doesn't need that, why would your type? (as additional text in your post, of course, not as a comment. And without an "edit" heading)

Comment: I think it's out of topic for the real world usage of TTX=TX. Number/Object is already defined. and there are so many usages such as to write Monad etc.

Comment: If there's no real-world use case, you're almost certainly going to get this question closed as "there is nothing to answer here". SO's main role is to get answers to programming problems, so something that even you would never use in real code just... isn't that. Fun thing to think about, interesting to discuss on a typescript forum, but [simply off-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: There are so many usage of TTX=TX like monad, and I don't think my question is unclear and to be closed.

Comment: Right, so: please talk about a real world use-case, because now you said there isn't one, _and_ that there is. Which is it? If there is one: nice! Plenty of TS experts here to help you do what you want to do, even if "declaring an idempotent typing" is not the way to do that. (after all, SO is about making sure people get the right solution to their problem. You're not just asking for yourself, but for every future visitor to SO, too).

Comment: For instance, Functors, such as pipeline-operator emulation, if you define Pipe<T>, it must be idempotence. My own code is currently very complicated and not worth to share here, and again @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, to define TTX=TX, we generally don't need an example, I think.

Comment: Indeed: good thing to add to the post.

Comment: "*The same can happen with monads, for example.*" - actually, no. If you have a proper algorithmic data type that is a monad, you must be able to construct a `T<T<X>>` - although you can `join` it, the type does not **auto**-flatten.

Comment: @Bergi In theory, yes, you are right, however, for inference capability of TypeScript, we often need to declare TTX=TX manually.

Comment: What is the concrete interface of the type that should do auto-flattening? How would the type definition look if it didn't auto-flatten? This question is not answerable if you don't post that code.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: @Bergi I appreciate your advice, but I don't think it's really necessary with that, and actually I do believe my question is pretty clearly defined, and fortunately had an answer here.  Thanks.

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks for your input, yeah, a couple of people addressed me the issue, it's very informative, in fact.

Comment: @Functor Yeah, but that answer is rather limited. Aplet123 just assumed the `InnerType<T>` to be `[T]`, it doesn't work for anything. (It doesn't even necessarily work for that).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
  Ok guys, now I posted the real-world use case code in my other question based on this QA answer. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861877/how-to-fix-the-broken-code-with-idempotent-self-flatten-types-in-typescript

Comment: Here's my refactored new question with my current refactored code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876135/typescript-is-type-predicates-user-defined-type-guard-functions-to-implement   Please investigate my new code and point me out the problem. Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write an idempotent wrapper around some inner type:

```
// just for reference, more practically this could be Promise<T>
type InnerType<T> = [T];
type IdempotentWrapper<X> = X extends InnerType<unknown> ? X : InnerType<X>;

type Foo = IdempotentWrapper<number>; // equivalent to InnerType<number>
type Bar = IdempotentWrapper<IdempotentWrapper<number>>; // equivalent to InnerType<number> as well
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you @Aplet123 !!

Comment: Notice that `IdempotentWrapper<[number]>` won't be equivalent to `InnerType<[number]>`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I am not really sure how the thing connected, but at least, I have a problem to implement in fact. If you have any idea, please comment to my Question thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861877/how-to-fix-the-broken-code-with-idempotent-self-flatten-types-in-typescript

Comment: @Aplet123 , I'm sorry I've found this solution eventually stop working. I posted my new question. Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876135/typescript-is-type-predicates-user-defined-type-guard-functions-to-implement