# How to fix the broken code with idempotent (self flatten) types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a question directly connected to my previous question

**[How to express idempotent (self flatten) types in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859942/how-to-express-idempotent-self-flatten-types-in-typescript)**

My purpose is to implement an **object that wraps JavaScript values to have `map(f)` method**.

The below is the simplified code and, **the first one works without error**.

Now, in **the second code, I made the** **`P` object with the type of idempotence**.

It should be (probably)

`P<P<unknown>> == P<unknown>`

```
type p<A> = {
  map: <B>(R: (a: A) => B) => P<B>
};

type P<A> =  //-------------idempotence
  A extends p<unknown>
  ? A
  : p<A>;
```

The code works as expected:

```
const x = P(5);     //  p<number>
const xx = P(P(5)); //  p<number>
```

; however, **instead, a new error occured:**

[image]

I investigated by myself for a long time, but no idea how this happens and the most importantly how to fix this.

Any idea? Thanks as always!

Also see **[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=63&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/N4KA9GC807fwxcQBcCeAHApgAgxgHgEEA%20HSHUHHAWwEMMAuHAgIRIAoAlZju5ogEpyZVsMhl8bEiAC%20AbhAgAxgHsAdgGcUOAArkWRADScAHgPEzqAeQBGAKyzKUAOgAmWAGYBLdVl0ATqrYAegcdo7OHKaCRiDU1ABE9BiJcQmU8Rk4WOoArjRYAXS2ADZYzJ50pZpY6dlq6j4A5nnFZRU4KAF5dVkZAG7VvcxsJhyevPw4QiI4YnO6E9GCgv04ssJ0mniEpIoqGto4pgZLAKyC8tkQ1FL5NLZFMo3HpqcUSxer17e7BPcCk8AiQZIctDo1DQMKpauQssQjPMkQBhTjNXi2ZgLCQ4FGWdYTKYWOY4qzZPgkiS3ZrLOirdYZJb0lwpCaCVkMDjNK7gMA4dSqHIBIIBJSyECgCBIGWy2WoTC4PZkChUWgMUbsbjEmaWeZ63TSOQHdDYPTEFVZIg5UwoXJuHaEPLqADWgoA7upyQB%20GZZZjKg6vHT6CiIsxU8kRJyuDw%20PyBYJFMLRqIxepJFJpdZqjK5ApFErlSrVWoZhKNFptIudbq9cvUIalEYsVjjSY4Sm60kG5YxNYZTY4bbm-ZKYMnM4cS7XDJ-QgPYEvI46d5T75XHDzgiL57jlc4KEwuGQBHGZF49GY7F6-EiQkdruzXFkxmd6bPkg0ukM7IJZkcmyniAVyPKzrcng4N4OymlgAC0RSil0mgcAATAAzAALJc4AAFQgEQAStIU6g6KokGwTgADkT56qwVFQTsgo6NsmjeM06g1l0QoYHQxSFHaAQ4ORXSKtRHBds6bqqJ6dHCAAZJ2tE9lRLggAAKmJNEfnRDHQQKqgsZobEcVxKBCpR2nMFJHrqLpamadgOwibx-FYIJOxUXQDF0OobjUd5w4BLgvhHnQKDeB0anUI5uBUTZMnqHpTGGcOxnsZxHTcaJZpUUQqnrHlDFqHkpT%20U8UEQr5EXhVg-nut4KAABbDuoQW2I1xQBGgOW4O6TXeMoLUlWVOAVc6wWlLV-nmdRCWeqpKAoRh2FrBwrl0AJRTCI%20OmklkuFgHIQA)**

**The simplest version with no error**

```
type pp<A> = {
  map: <B>(R: (a: A) => B) => pp<B>
};

const P = <A,>(x: A) =>
  Object.defineProperty(Object(x),
    "map",
    {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      value: <B,>(f: (a: A) => B) => P(f(x))
    }) as pp<A>;

const x = P(5);     //  pp<number>
const xx = P(P(5)); //  pp<pp<number>>

const compose =
  <A, B, C>(g: (b: B) => C) =>
    (f: (a: A) => B) =>
      (a: A) =>// g(f(a))
        P(a).map(f).map(g);
// no error
```

[image]

---

**Idempotent version with Type-error**

```
type p<A> = {
  map: <B>(R: (a: A) => B) => P<B>
};

type P<A> =  //-------------idempotence
  A extends p<unknown>
  ? A
  : p<A>;

const P = <A,>(x: A) =>
  Object.defineProperty(Object(x),
    "map",
    {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      value: <B,>(f: (a: A) => B) => P(f(x))
    }) as P<A>;

const x = P(5);     //  p<number>
const xx = P(P(5)); //  p<number>

const compose =
  <A, B, C>(g: (b: B) => C) =>
    (f: (a: A) => B) =>
      (a: A) =>// g(f(a))
        P(a).map(f).map(g);  // f is type-error ts(2345)
/*   Argument of type '(a: A) => B' is not assignable to parameter of type '((a: unknown) => B) & ((a: A) => B)'.
Type '(a: A) => B' is not assignable to type '(a: unknown) => B'.
Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'A'.
    'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.ts(2345)
(parameter) f: (a: A) => B   */
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBACjAvDAPAQQHwAoAeAuGNASiQxiwG8AoGGAWwEMAHAlAIWwDMCsGDjSMNiURk4WTriJEqAXxlVQkWDiTwsAViIBuWnoD0+2kxRgArnQBGAUwBOGReGgwcq5OPFadMQ8dMWbeypHZRhQOiYQCGskGlQ0ABohJIBhbABzHksCYUEUkQc9cm5yPkICoQK4ot5+At90iV5paqL1BiIAOkYmCS6erHSdIA) ?

Comment: Actually, no, the types in your code linked are nested, not idempotent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the "idempotent type" thing cannot be resolved by TypeScript when it has to use generics. When looking at `P<A>` (where `A` is the type parameter from `compose`), TypeScript doesn't known whether that `A extends p<A>` or not, so it (rightfully) has to assume it might be either. The `P(a)` call inside `compose` has a return type of `P<A>`, which TypeScript correctly resolves to `p<unknown> | p<A>` - which has a `map` method with an argument type of `((a: unknown) => B) & ((a: A) => B)`, to which `f` is incompatible.

---

That said, your `P` function is broken as well, and not really idempotent:

- It mutates its argument (bad idea in general) but claims to call the `map` callback with the original value. `P([1, 2]).map(arr => arr.map(x=>x+1))` does compile and is legitimately expected to return `P([2, 3])`, but actually results in the string `"1,21"` at runtime. Go figure.
- It casts its argument to an object. `P(P(5))` (your `xx` example) has type `P<number>` which claims to call the `map` callback with a number, but actually calls it with a `Number` instance.

If you try to implement the `Identity` functor, just make it return a new object, and don't try to make an "idempotent type" from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the first one, `"1,21"`, this is because of my sample choice of the method name `"map"`, if I did `"mp"` for the sample, `P([1, 2]).mp(arr => arr.map(x=>x+1))` the result is `P([2,3])`, so this is not for mutation. I think you purposely chosen the "map", and I don't know why you connected the confusion of the method name of Array.map to mutation concept?

Comment: For Primitive values, they becomes object, for sure, and not only `P(P(5))`, but also `P(5)` is object, and this is nothing related to `map`  callback. It's related to the type constructor `P` This is also the claim you made that I don't understand.

Comment: @Functor I was using an array only as an example of the confusion your `P` function causes. If you named the method `mp`, then the counterexample would be that `P({mp() { return "foo"}}).mp(x => x.mp())` should be equivalent to `P("foo")` according to the method signature, but it isn't. Your `P` function is not generic - if it should be, it must support any arbitrary type for `A`.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding your intention, the counter example aims for the exception of` `undefined/Null`  argument, I've noticed that issue and implemented `None`, however, that is so far an extra value of the code since we need to fucus on the fundamental issue of typing idempotent.

Comment: I'm afraid to say what I am uncomfortable with your current answer is the answer is focusing on the P implementation itself. In my real code includes `None` or `(isType(typeP)(X))
            ? X
            : customType(typeP)` thing to make P idempotent; however doing so makes the sample code complicated and hard to follow the issue of idempotence itself.

Comment: Finally, I think it's not a proper approach to use `Identity` functor for this pipeline operation, because the original object is idempotent. I need to preserver the original structure even if it's `[Number: 5]`, not `{value: 5}`

Comment: No, the counterexample is not specific to aim for `undefined`. It aims for anything that is of similar structure (same method name) but different behaviour than your `P` type, as these collide with your method. It is impossible to preserve the original structure *and* add methods to it in a compatible way, if the original structure is arbitrary. It might help if you showed your actual code and your actual use case - your current example looks for too much like the identity functor.

Comment: Here's my refactored new question with my current refactored code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876135/typescript-is-type-predicates-user-defined-type-guard-functions-to-implement Actually, I think you are right to indicate `P` itself has something wrong. Please investigate my new code and point me out the problem. Thanks as always!

Comment: @Functor Thanks. Still, can you add your actual use case and why you are trying to achieve idempotence?

Comment: As I addressed in my question, basically I try to implement pipeline-operator like F# `|>` that is monad in nature, and idempotence so that never has type of `P<P<T>>` ; it's same as `Promises.then` is idempotent. Is it clear?

Comment: @Functor The more I think of it, I come to the conclusion that there are no idempotent types (apart from `type ID<T> = T`). Especially not if they're properly monadic and not broken like promises. Even `Promise<Promise<number>>` is a valid type that is distinct from `Promise<number>` 
 - that you cannot easily construct it with standard promise libs doesn't matter (and actually there are algebraic promise libraries that *do* allow `Promise.of(Promise.of(5))`). What is "idempotent" is the `then` function, it has the type `Promise<T>.then(f: T => U | Promise<U>): Promise<U>`.

Comment: `Promise` or `Array` any Functors generally has structures; however, `Object(5) === Object(Object(5))` that is idempotent other than `Identity` function, and you are right in a sense, every Object is the identity function; for `5`: `(a:5) => a)`, or "`foo"`: `(a:"foo") => a`

Comment: The pipeline operator in F#, `a |> f`, since the object is `a` that is the idempotent object:  `Object(5) === Object(Object(5))` I need to emulate this without having extra structures. I basically try to add `|>` method to the object that is idempotent in nature.

Comment: Yes, functors (the types) have structures, and those are not idempotent. "An object `a`" is not idempotent. The functions that do construct them, be it `Object` or `Promise.resolve`, maybe be idempotent, and you can type *them* accordingly. E.g. `Object<T>(arg: T): T extends {} ? T : T extends null | undefined | void ? {} : PrimitiveWrapper<T>`. (Although in TypeScript an overload might be easier?). And the same holds for the type of your `|>` operator (although I'm missing how it can be idempotent if it has two operands)

Comment: null/undefined is an another subject than every object is idempotent in a a language. So again, I need to prepare `None` for the special treatment in JavaScript in reality. I mean if the language treat the null/undefined concept as `None` that has `|>` method natively, there is no problem in theory,

Comment: I probably do need to study your typing to the Object itself, and examine if I can do better in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, at least I figured out for the issue of my latest code for idempotent, and answered by myself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876135/typescript-is-type-predicates-user-defined-type-guard-functions-to-implement/69878330#69878330 However, the fundamental issue should be as same as before.

Comment: Probably now we share the concept of my purpose, and I'm pretty much interested in your actual sample implementation using  `Object<T>(arg: T): T extends {} ? T : T extends null | undefined | void ? {} : PrimitiveWrapper<T>`, I would appreciate and gracefully accept your answer in the latest question there, Thanks a lot!!!